# Update the host field in Grant privileges in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have an existing table and I want to update host part in privileges using Grant command

```
mysql> show grants
    -> ;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for ssc@localhost                                                                                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'ssc'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*ABCDEFABCDEF' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `ssc`.* TO 'ssc'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                     |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What do you want it to be changed for?

Comment: @peterm I want to change it to allow from all ip addresses.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to connect as `ssc` from anywhere you have to create an additional user and grant him necessary rights

```
CREATE USER 'ssc'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '<your password>';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `ssc`.* TO 'ssc'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Read more about that in [Adding User Accounts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html)